# How can we show @ character keyboard on focus on main keyboard page without the need to press the 123 keypad for fetching?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-redux, react-native

I am new in react-native, I want to show the @ character in keyboard when on focus on email Text Input. Please provide me the syntax, how can I open the Keyboard with @ character by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `keyboardType` property to `'email-address'`.

```
keyboardType = {'email-address'}
```